# Specify camera area of interest

Tags: camera

I want to have the camera looking only to a limited viewing field. 
Due to geometry reasons I am not free to point the camera in the room. In real camera technology this is named AOI or ROI. Is there a solution for this?
Right now I place a wall in front of it with a open window of my view.

PS: I know I can limit the viewing/rendering field, but I really want to simulate the camera itself as best as possible.

Comment: You could change [Camera lens](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/camera/lens.html) settings, particulalry focal length if you'd like to make objects appear closer without moving camera.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to have a quadratic view field.